# How many roots has the equation $x^3+x^2+x+1=0$ modulo $340$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

Question:

> How many roots has the equation $x^3+x^2+x+1=0$ modulo $340$?

I am fairly sure this is a very standard problem but I cannot seem to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem.

So far I have gathered there is one-to-one correspondence from $\mathbb{Z}/\langle340\rangle$ to $\mathbb{Z}/\langle4\rangle\times\mathbb{Z}/\langle17\rangle\times\mathbb{Z}/\langle5\rangle$. What can I do next? I know that there is a bijective ring homomorphism $x+\langle 340 \rangle\to(x+\langle 4 \rangle\ ,x+\langle 17 \rangle\ , x+\langle 5 \rangle)$.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem can be used if you find all solutions $\pmod p^k$ for every $p^k\mid 340$ ($p^k$ is a power of prime $p$ in 340).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

There are $2$ solutions mod $4$, $3$ solutions mod $5$, and $3$ solutions mod $17$.

Comment: Thank you! However I have a few issues, is there an elegant way of showing there are only $3$ solutions in mod $17$? I kind of verified by hand, which was quite tedious. Also, does this therefore imply that the number of solutions is $18=2\times 3\times 3$?

Comment: Mod $17$:  $x^3+x^2+x+1\equiv0\iff \dfrac{x^4-1}{x-1}\equiv0\iff (x+1)(x^2+1)\equiv0\iff x\equiv-1$ or $ x\equiv\pm4$; yes, the answer is $18$ by the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Answer (score 3):

The equation $x^3+x^2+x+1$ is just
$$x^2(x+1)+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1)$$
which has one root $-1=339\pmod{340}$. For the rest, you need to see if $-1$ is a root of unity$\pmod{340}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I am not too sure about the part 'you need to see if $-1$ is a root of unity'. In particular I am not sure what root of unity am I checking over and how will this help. Since I have not seen this approach before, could you please elaborate or perhaps link me something similar so I could study on this approach?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol

Comment: and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol#Calculations_using_the_Legendre_symbol